# generating runtime html string is not rendering as html

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablestring

I', return a NSMutableString with html in it, now the problem is when i save it it renders as string in browser. any idea what can be done about it?

```
<html>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

it is rendered as it is, browser is not detecting it as html and display only helloworld, instead whole of this string is rendered as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render your string that contains HTML  tags like:

```
NSString *YOURSTRING = @"YOUR String as contains Html tags";
NSData *data = [YOURSTRING dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[YOURWEBVIEW loadData:data  MIMEType:@"text/plain" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `<html>` instead of `</html>` in the end.

Could you give code please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you NSLog out the mutable sting I'm going to assume it will print out like this

```
&lt;html&gt;<br>
&lt;body&gt;<br>
Hello World<br>
&lt;/body&gt;<br>
&lt;/html&gt;
```

In which case you will have to make sure the entities in the post are parsed.

You can do this the lazy way by using

```
 replaceOccurancesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<" 
 replaceOccurancesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"
```

Or you can do it the proper way and use something to convert the entities properly in which case I would suggest
https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/downloads/list

Comment: NSLog gives < and >, but a html designer software gives &lt and &gt